# Difference between BOOST_FOREACH and c++11 for range based loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, foreach

1. What are the main differences between `BOOST_FOREACH` and c++11 range based loop?
2. Is there a specific situation where I would want to use `BOOST_FOREACH` instead of range based loop or vice versa?

After executing a little test with `std::vector` filled with 1,000,000 `int` variables I found out that `BOOST_FOREACH` is a little bit slower than range based loop (took  about 1.25 times longer than for a ranged based loop).

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a use for `boost::foreach` in new code anymore.  I think it's only useful in old code, before there were ranged-based loops.

Comment: Do you mean `BOOST_FOREACH`?

Comment: @Barry Yes, I do. Let me edit that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The main difference is that range-for is a language construct, while `BOOST_FOREACH` is a macro doing lots of magic under the hood to do something that looks like that language construct. It is trying to do exactly the same thing with the limitations of pre-C++11. The goal of `BOOST_FOREACH` *is* range-for.

There is exactly one situation where I would even think of using `BOOST_FOREACH` instead of range-for, and it is iterating over a container of tuples where you want to unroll the tuple:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
int key, value;
BOOST_FOREACH(boost::tie(key, value), m)
{
    // do something with key and value here
}
```

as compared to:

```
int key, value;
for (const auto& pair : m) 
{
    std::tie(key, value) = pair;
    // do something
}
```

I like that you can put the `tie` directly into the loop header, although ultimately that's such a minor advantage that it's hardly worth even considering this as being a decision. Use range-for. Always.

---

C++17 introduced [structured bindings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), which removed even that minor syntactical advantage:

```
for (auto const& [key, value] : m)
{
    // do something
}
```

At this point, there is no reason whatsoever to use `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Comment: Which one is better? I'm working on a project, the project included boost but they just used foreach. I removed the foreach parts using boost and corrected them with the standard for loop. I think it was unnecessary. What are you thinking ?

Comment: @FatihMertDoğancan Yeah, use the standard language for loop.

Answer (score 2):

boost offers BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH which allows you to traverse containers backwards. The for ranged loop does not provide an similar functionality.