# Alternate of ranged based for?

Tags: c++11, boost

How do you write the alternate for "ranged based for" that is a part of c++11 in older versions of C++

```
for (boost::property_tree::ptree::iterator iter = root.begin() ; iter != root.end() ; iter++)
    {
        for (auto& array_element : iter->second)
        {
           //Some Lines
        }
   }
```

Comment: A normal iterator loop? Using an [algorithm function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)?

Comment: How do you write that ?

Comment: You already have an iterator loop shown in your example... Think about what that first outer loop is doing, then think about how it could be used on another container...

Comment: Or you could use [`BOOST_FOREACH`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/foreach.html) ? See also [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27027825/253056).